# React Native: Why does object destructuring not work inside regular functions?

Tags: javascript, function, react-native, object-destructuring

Using use object destructuring to destructe my state before sending a call to my REST API and it only works inside of an arrow function for me.  I tried calling it inside of a regular function and I kept getting an error that it was undefined.  Code examples are below

I'm calling the function in a child component, I'm not sure if that makes a difference.  Your help would be greatly appreciated so I can learn this concept, thanks!

**Code I don't understand why its breaking**

```
async get() {
 const { userData } = this.state
 try {
  const response = await http.get('/v1', {
    userData
  })
  console.log('response', response);
  await this.setState({friends: response.data});
 } catch(err) {
  console.log("error getting friends ", err);
 }
}
```

**Code that works **

```
get = async () => {
 const { userData } = this.state
 try {
  const response = await http.get('/v1', {
    userData
  })
  console.log('response', response);
  await this.setState({friends: response.data});
 } catch(err) {
  console.log("error getting friends ", err);
 }
}
```

Comment: `Async storage` is not valid JavaScript. The first is probably a method, the second is an async arrow function. You can only use `await` in an async function. So that's one reason why the first one does not work. The second reason is that [`this` works differently in arrow functions vs "normal" functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34361379/218196). Since you are using `this`, the behavior will be different. Nothing at all related to destructuring. Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/34361379/218196.

Comment: Thanks @FelixKling!  I actually didn't clean up my code as well as I should when I copied it in.  I just updated the post to include the proper code.  I get that error even when its an async function and Async Storage (which I had commented out in my code) isn't there.

Comment: That still leaves the `this` difference. That will be the reason. See the linked question.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code won't work because of `this` keyword. [Understanding this keyword in javascript](https://medium.com/quick-code/understanding-the-this-keyword-in-javascript-cb76d4c7c5e8)

To make it works. You can bind the method in the constructor of the class. For example.

```js
class Example {

  constructor(){
    // ...
    this.get = this.get.bind(this); // Or bind the method that you call get method
  }

  async get() {
   const { userData } = this.state
   try {
    const response = await http.get('/v1', {
      userData
    })
    console.log('response', response);
    await this.setState({friends: response.data});
   } catch(err) {
    console.log("error getting friends ", err);
   }
  }
}
```